# How to deduct VAT for Guernsey in Magento?

Tags: magento, tax, rete

My Magento won't deduct VAT from the order if the customer is from the Guernsey Island. Magento is hiding TAX but not deduct it?
Any suggestions?

Comment: This *may* be on topic on http://magento.stackexchange.com, but definitely not here

Comment: Can't find anything in this regards ;(

Comment: This would not be on-topic in any SE site in its current form. Readers would need to see some context/code and some prior effort.

Comment: If not here ... where should I ask ? Is not the main purpose of the forum to help sometimes ?
I'm not changing the code, everything works on one store but won't on another with the same settings. Checked it all and it seems to be OK but still don't work. What code I have to show you ? I can post a pictures but will it help ?
Just asking, what I must set/check to make it work if the customer is from Jersey or Guernsey. There people don't pay VAT so price should be VAT-excluded.
If you don't like the title i can change it but it will still not solve my issue. :)
No offence buddy ...

Comment: Oooh I will post the same question on Magento.Stackoverflow. Somehow instead post it there i posted it here .... ??? how ??? why ??? no clue it suppose to be on Magento ... :)